# Can I visit to Denmark/Faroe islands with a German blue card (for tourism 3-4 weeks)

Tags: visa, resident-permit, schengen, residence-cards, denmark

Can I visit to Denmark/Faroe islands with a German blue card. I'm planning a trip to Faroe Islands and Denmark for 3-4 weeks and would like to know if need a separate visa for the same. I hold a German blue valid till 2026.

Any info on this would be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend in your citizenship, which you haven't provided.

The Faroe Islands is **not** part of the Schengen Area.

The rules that would otherwise apply to Schengen Area residence permit/card holders, does **not** apply for the Faroe Islands.

If your citizenship normaly requires a visa to enter the Schengen Area, then you must apply for a visa that is **specifically valid** for the Faroe Islands.

> @phoog: More specific information about travel to the Faroe Islands with a Schengen residence permit, including information about how to apply for an "entry permit," is available at:
> [Visa to the Faroe Island or Greenland - How to apply](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Short-stay-visa/Visa-to-the-Faroe-Island-or-Greenland#D76C1777FE974D9A97505FD07C500E4F3X)

---

> [Passport & visas - Visit Faroe Islands](https://www.visitfaroeislands.com/plan-your-stay/before-you-arrive-in-the-faroe-islands/passport-visas/)
> **B. EU-COUNTRY AND SCHENGEN COUNTRY**
> You do not need a visa or other permit to visit the Faroe Islands. You may enter with a passport, or, for visits, a national ID card (that includes a photo) from one of the below countries. This only applies to **citizens** of the below countries.
>
> > It is **NOT** sufficient to be a foreign resident; you must be a **citizen**.
>
> ...
> **C. OTHER COUNTRIES**
> ...
> **The Faroe Islands are NOT part of the Schengen Area. Consequently, people cannot enter the Faroe Islands based on their Schengen visas or Danish visa. When a visa is applied for at the Danish Embassy, it must be specifically for the Faroe Islands.**

Comment: More specific information about travel to the Faroe Islands with a Schengen residence permit, including information about how to apply for an "entry permit," is available at https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Short-stay-visa/Visa-to-the-Faroe-Island-or-Greenland